# Query Improvement: foreach

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following model function and I was wanting to know how I could improve it and also pull the needed `$row` out when needed so that I dont get a PHP error.

**How I am pulling the required data:**

```
    $data['companyName'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails('coreCompanyName');
```

**Errors:**

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$coreContactName
Undefined property: stdClass::$coreContactEmail
```

**Model:**

```
function companyDetails()
{
    $this->db->select('coreCompanyName, coreContactName, coreContactEmail');

    $this->db->from('core');

    $whereData = array('coreCompanyName' => $companyName, 'coreContactName' => $companyContactName, 'coreContactEmail' => $companyContactEmail);

    $this->db->where($whereData);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result = '';

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {

        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $result .= $row->coreCompanyName;
            $result .= $row->coreContactName;
            $result .= $row->coreContactEmail;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: After the foreach, what does a `print_r` of `$row` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * WHERE ARE : $companyName, $companyContactName, $companyContactEmail being defined ?
 * WHY return 'companyName' WHEN You are quering based on the '$companyName' ???
 * Your query wil fail with out it, that that's all your using ?
 *
 */
function companyDetails() {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT companyName FROM core WHERE coreCompanyName = ? AND coreContactName = ? AND coreContactEmail = ? LIMIT 1",
    array($companyName, $companyContactName, $companyContactEmail));
    return ($query->num_rows() == 1) ? $query->row()->companyName : FALSE;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
$this->db->select('coreCompanyName, coreContactName, coreContactEmail');
```

not

```
$this->db->select('coreCompanyName','coreContactName','coreContactEmail');
```

See reference http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select

To limit to a specific set of records, use the where() function. e.g.

```
$this->db->where('companyId', $companyId);
```

Comment: Thank you Chui but this now pulls all data out of the table instead of the required data.  Any Ideas?

Comment: I added a sample of how to filter in the answer. What do you want to filter on?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$this->db->select('coreCompanyName','coreContactName','coreContactEmail');
```

To:

```
$this->db->select('coreCompanyName, coreContactName, coreContactEmail');
```

Now, you said this pulls all the data, but you aren't actually filtering the result. I wonder what the required data is

Comment: I think thats what my issue is I am unsure how to filter the result what would be the best way to attack this. I will upload an adjusted model now